# How do I make cars on a one-dimensional track avoid collisions?

Tags: three.js

Using three.js, I use a simple spline to represent a road. Cars can only move forward on the spline. A car should be able to slow-down behind a slow moving car. I know how to calculate the distance between 2 cars, but how to calculate the proper speed in each game update?

At the moment I simply do something like this:

```
this.speed += (this.maxSpeed - this.speed) * 0.02; // linear interpolation to maxSpeed

// the position on the spline (0.0 - 1.0)
this.position += this.speed / this.road.spline.getLength();
```

This works. But how to implement the slow-down part?

```
// transform from floats (0.0 - 1.0) into actual units
var carInFrontPosition = carInFront.position * this.road.spline.getLength();
var myPosition = this.position * this.road.spline.getLength();

var distance = carInFrontPosition - myPosition;

// WHAT TO DO HERE WITH THE DISTANCE?
// HOW TO CALCULATE MY NEW SPEED?
```

Obviously I have to somehow take current speed of the cars into account for calculation.

Besides different maxSpeeds, I want each car to also have a different mass (causing it to accelerate slower/faster). But this mass has to be then also taken into account for braking (slowing down) so they don't crash into each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT***

The current solution has the following problem: The applied braking force is static. That means if we randomly put a car on the road, other cars might be unable to break in time (since we always lower the velocity by a static braking force). I though I could scale the force somehow, but without much success (it causes oscillation).

Now I calculate the needed braking force on the fly.

Stopping distance still calculated the same way:

```
    var distanceToKeep = (CAR_LENGTH * 1.5) * 1.5;
    var stoppingDistance = ((carInFront.lane === this.lane) ? 0 : this.lane.spline.getLength()) + carInFront.position + carInFront.velocity - this.position - distanceToKeep;
```

But then:

```
if (stoppingDistance < 300) {
    // Formula from: http://www.gcsescience.com/pen33-work-energy-calculations.htm
    this.acceleration = -(0.5 * (this.velocity * this.velocity) / stoppingDistance);
}
else {
    this.acceleration = force;
}
```

This will gradually slow us down if the distance is below 300 units. If we spawn a car in front of us only 100 units away, we will brake much harder. In previous solution it would cause a crash.

Still there is a problem left. If we stand still behind a car, and the car in front starts moving, we won't move until the distance is 300 units... So again a static component that causes problems. I solved it by scaling the stoppingDistance based on velocity, which also brings back the reaction time:

```
var effectiveDistance = stoppingDistance * (100 / Math.min(100, Math.max(0.1, this.velocity)));
effectiveDistance *= this.reactionTime; // *= 0.0 - 1.0

if (effectiveDistance <= 300) {
   // the rest is the same, we still divide by stoppingDistance here
```

This works very well. No matter where I spawn cars on a lane, the other cars will always stop in time and will not crash into each other.

***/EDIT***

I solved it now using proper math (thanks to Anko for the hint).

A car's $position property previously was assigned the "point-position" on the spline (0.0 - 1.0). For easier calculation I now use the actual position in units on the spline. For velocity I use units as well. From update method:

```
this.position += this.velocity * dt;
this.velocity += this.acceleration * dt; // we calculate the acceleration below

if (this.velocity < 0) {
    this.velocity = 0;
}
else if (this.velocity > this.maxVelocity) {
    this.velocity = this.maxVelocity;
}

[...]

// Calculate point on lane (0.0 - 1.0)
var pointOnLane = 1 / this.road.spline.getLength() * this.position;
var positionVector = this.road.spline.getPointAt(pointOnLane);

this.mesh.position.set(positionVector.x, 5, positionVector.z);
```

Now for the acceleration calculation:

```
var force = 5;
var reactionTime = 0.5;

if (carInFront !== null) {

        var distanceToKeep = (CAR_LENGTH * 1.5) * 1.5;
        // Formulas from: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese302/lab-content/STOPPING_DISTANCE_DOC.pdf
        var stoppingDistance = carInFront.position + carInFront.velocity - this.position - distanceToKeep;
        var stoppingTime = this.velocity / force;
        var reactionDistance = stoppingDistance * reactionTime;
        var brakingDistance = (0.5 * this.velocity * stoppingTime) + reactionDistance;

        if (stoppingDistance < brakingDistance) {
            this.acceleration = -force / reactionTime;
        }
        else
        {
            this.acceleration = force / reactionTime;
        }

}
else
{
    this.acceleration = force / reactionTime;
}
```

So this already works perfectly. See how they all line up behind the very slow car:

[image]

Currently for positive and negative (braking) acceleration I use the same force which results in very long braking times (and looks unrealistic). But it should be easy to fix by calculating braking force or braking reaction time based on distance and/or velocity.